# Reuse floatActionButton android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a floatActionButton and want to reuse it across activities, so i don't need on each activity to call the onclick method,

At the moment i have something like this:

**Helper**

```
public class FloatButtonToolbar extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("ENTERED","GOTIT");
             Intent i = new Intent(FloatButtonToolbar.this,CameraCapture.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**main xml(the one that i want to reuse)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.FloatButtonToolbar">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**now on my activity xml i have this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.FamilyLibrary"
    android:paddingTop="6dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="#f1c40f"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp" />
```

the thing is in the first example above, i have the onclick listener but it is not working, it doesn't enter in the onclick, the log never display :S

Any sugestion?

Comment: Please stop adding the irrelevant `android-studio` tag to all your posts. The IDE you are using is **not relevant** to your app issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse the same view across activities.  Views belong to an activity.  You'll have to setup the onClick in each activity.  The best you could do is make a custom child of FloatingActionButton that hard codes an onClick behavior in its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Views cannot be used across activities as such, but fragments can be. So, in android, if you require certain views or viewgroups to be accessible across activities, then you can make a fragment of those viewgroups and then use them across activities. So, in this case you can make a fragment containing the fab and then reserve the lower right corner in each activity layout for the fragment and when the activity is created place the fragment there.
For more information on fragments you can use the following references:-

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html